# Points Ranking in Laravel where points are equal

Tags: php, sql, laravel, rank, leaderboard

I am trying to work out how to correct display the rank of points to show a leaderboard.

I currently have the following in my Modal

```
 public function getPointrankAttribute(){
    $year = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->year;

    $pointrank = Points::query()
        ->select('member_id')->selectRaw('SUM(value) as TotalPoints')
        ->where('Year','=', $year)
        ->groupBy('member_id')
        ->orderByDesc('Totalpoints')
        ->get();

    return $pointrank->search(function($points){
        return $points->member_id == $this->id;
    }) + 1;

}
```

This works well, however it is using the row position in the table to show the rank, so the first record is 1st and the 2nd record shows as 2nd.

However the issue arises when members have the same total points, because under this the rank is based on position on in the table

See the following example

```
|member_id|totalpoints|
|   12    | 20        |
|    3    |  10       |
|   10    |  10       |
|    5    |   5       |
```

In this example based on my current solution

Member 12 = 1st, Member 3 = 2nd, Member 10 = 3rd, Member 5 = 4th

What I want is the following

Member 12 = 1st, Member 3 = 2nd, Member 10 = 2nd, Member 5 = 4th

It would be awesome if I could also add "=" as well when we have more than 1 member sharing that position (as in Member 3 and 10 in this case)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need the database version of assigning rank do add some sample data from points table in your question

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thanks for your reply. Do you require more information than the temp table  created by my query? I have listed the Member_id and Totalpoints which are the 2 fields in the table. Want I want to do use a Rank method for placings vs using the Row Number, as listed in my question above.

Comment: Yes I need sample data from points table so that I can suggest SQL query that will be returning ranks for users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rank for your users you will need to assign rank to distinct total points first, using laravel collection helper you can create separate ranks collection irrespective of member ids like

```
$collection =collect(
[
  [
    "member_id" => 12,
    "totalpoints" => 20
  ],
  [
    "member_id" => 3,
    "totalpoints" => 10
  ],
  [
    "member_id" => 10,
    "totalpoints" => 10
  ],
  [
    "member_id" => 5,
    "totalpoints" => 5
  ],
]
);

$ranks = $collection->unique('totalpoints')
                    ->values()
                    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $index) {
                        return [$item['totalpoints'] => $index + 1];
                    });
```

> Make sure the original collection should be ordered based on total points.

The above will create an array of distinct points as keys and values as ranks based on total points like

```
Array
(
    [20] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [5] => 3
)
```

Now you can search your members based on id from original collection and get their respective rank from ranks array like

```
$id = 10;
$ranks[$collection->firstWhere("member_id", $id)["totalpoints"]];
```

There is another way to get ranks for your records directly from database if the vendor database supports window functions like [RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank)

> What I want is the following :Member 12 = 1st, Member 3 = 2nd, Member 10 = 2nd, Member 5 = 4th

To achieve your desired results you just need to remove `->values()` from above code so that your results are not re indexed

```
$ranks = $collection->unique('totalpoints')
                    ->mapWithKeys(function ($item, $index) {
                        return [$item['totalpoints'] => $index + 1];
                    });

Array
(
    [20] => 1
    [10] => 2
    [5] => 4
)
```

[DEMO](https://implode.io/r9GanP)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the only issue I have here is that Member_id 5 with 5 points is listed as 3 (3rd) when I need it to shown (4th). But I an add this solution in for another project

Comment: @Brendan I thought if points are same for one or more users the rank will be same, also can you elaborate why there is no third rank ? Logically there should be a third rank, also updated my answer for your desired output

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, this is because in my case here, the 2 equal third's will skip the 4th Rank. I am trying to copy the Rank Function in Excel. Which in this case also skips 3rd place.